# GoogleAuthException thrown when using audience:server:client_id:<SEERVER_CLIENT_ID>

Tags: google-plus-signin

I am using the google plus api to login my user with the oauth2 infrastructure. I want to use backend authentication service. I followed this guide https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth step by step. However every time I call

`scope1 = "audience:server:client_id:" + SERVER_CLIENT_ID;
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, account, scope1);`

It throws the above exception. I tried all the solutions given by stackoverflow as well as other blogs and nothing seems to change.

Is there a way to verify in more deep the cause of this problem. I mean some debugging tool in "google developer console" or android side to know more specifically whats going on.

logcat output:

`V/GLSActivity(3383): AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
V/AuthAccountOperation(18778): offline access is not requested; requesting access token
I/GLSUser(3383): [GLSUser] getTokenFromCache: [account: <ELLIDED:-15230>, callingPkg: com.clanpid.mobile.restaurant.app, service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login]
I/GLSUser(3383): [GLSUser] getTokenFromGoogle [account: <ELLIDED:-15230>, callingPkg: com.clanpid.mobile.restaurant.app, service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
I/GLSUser(3383): [GLSUser] getAuthtoken(<ELLIDED:-15230>, oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login) -> status: null)
I/GLSUser(3383): [GLSUser] Extracting token using key: Auth
W/GLSUser(3383): [GLSUser] Permission for com.clanpid.mobile.restaurant.app to access oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login will be managed remotely.
V/AuthAccountOperation(18778): access token request successful
I/GLSUser(3383): [GLSUser] getTokenFromCache: [account: <ELLIDED:-15230>, callingPkg: com.clanpid.mobile.restaurant.app, service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login]
D/UserAccessTokenFetcher(25646): am.pablo.vc@gmail.com
I/GLSUser(3383): [GLSUser] getTokenFromCache: [account: <ELLIDED:-15230>, callingPkg: com.clanpid.mobile.restaurant.app, service: audience:server:client_id:1074993820719-dlcpq2f2ev9pnlmlghclteakv50ivft1.apps.googleusercontent.com]
I/GLSUser(3383): [GLSUser] getTokenFromGoogle [account: <ELLIDED:-15230>, callingPkg: com.clanpid.mobile.restaurant.app, service: audience:server:client_id:1074993820719-dlcpq2f2ev9pnlmlghclteakv50ivft1.apps.googleusercontent.com
W/GLSActivity(3383): gms.StatusHelper Status from wire: INVALID_AUDIENCE status: null
I/GLSUser(3383): [GLSUser] getAuthtoken(<ELLIDED:-15230>, audience:server:client_id:1074993820719-dlcpq2f2ev9pnlmlghclteakv50ivft1.apps.googleusercontent.com) -> status: UNKNOWN)
I/GLSUser(3383): [GLSUser] Extracting token using key: Auth
W/GLSActivity(3383): gms.StatusHelper Status from wire: INVALID_AUDIENCE status: null
W/System.err(25646): com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    final String SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";
    String token = null;
    try {
        token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(),
                Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient),
                "oauth2:" + SCOPES);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Timber.e(e, "Error retrieving ID token.");
    } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
        Timber.e(e, "Error retrieving ID token.");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks David, sorry for coming back to you so late. I did not try your suggestion since I moved to Amazon Cognito SSO. My server app takes off a heavy load when using Cognito. Anyways the error that I was having seemed to be related to the project that I had was too old, then google did some changes in GAE and for some reason they messed up this old project. Starting a fresh project works well.